# Does Aptana Studio 3 support less css compile?

Tags: compiler-construction, aptana, less

I wonder if Aptana Studio 3 has less css compiler feature. I used the program with Simpless but I didn't have the Simpless turned on by chance. I edited and saved the less file and a css file was created automatically. I searched google but can't find it has that feature. 
I even moved the Simpless to other drive but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems just a little over a year ago it needed [just a few tweaks](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/suggestions/357-less-support) to support LESS. I have not found anything more official than that discussion posting to verify.

[This issue is still open at present](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3896?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel), but seems to deal more with some editor features as opposed to actual compiling.

However, simply by your testimony that it *is working* would seem to answer your question. And if the changes to make it work were in fact as simple as the first post link above indicates, I don't know why it would not have been incorporated within the last year.

For syntax highlighting, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752123/advanced-custom-syntax-coloring-for-aptana-studio-3-less).

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. while I testing the feature, I found it doesn't support fully, for example child selector( > ) doesn't work. So I returned to Simpless.

Answer (score 0):

this answer for windows

LESS + Aptana on Windows.
https://less.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/17-window-user-aptana-studio